# Tynker GUI Calculator Python Multiplication and Division doesn't work even after revisiting and trying out other solutions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Python GUI Calculator, and after trying a bunch of times, for some reason multiplication and division do not work for some reason. I revisited the tutorial a dozen times and even asked a friend but they do not know what is going on. I would really be grateful for any help.

This has been a little frustrating for a while.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

box = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=6)
box.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=15, pady=15)


def buttonClick(number):
  current = box.get()
  box.delete(0, END)
  box.insert(0, current + str(number))


def buttonClear():
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonAdd():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "addition"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonEqual():
  secondNumber = box.get()
  box.delete(0, END)

  if math == "addition":
    box.insert(0, numOne + int(secondNumber))

    if math == "subtraction":
      box.insert(0, numOne - int(secondNumber))

    if math == "multiplication":
      box.insert(0, numOne * int(secondNumber))

  if math == "division":
    box.insert(0, numOne / int(secondNumber))


def buttonSubtract():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "subtraction"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonMultiply():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "multiplication"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonDivide():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "division"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


Button1 = Button(root,
                 text="1",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(1))
Button2 = Button(root,
                 text="2",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(2))
Button3 = Button(root,
                 text="3",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(3))
Button4 = Button(root,
                 text="4",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(4))
Button5 = Button(root,
                 text="5",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(5))
Button6 = Button(root,
                 text="6",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(6))
Button7 = Button(root,
                 text="7",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(7))
Button8 = Button(root,
                 text="8",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(8))
Button9 = Button(root,
                 text="9",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(9))
Button0 = Button(root,
                 text="0",
                 padx=37,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(0))

ButtonAdd = Button(root, text="+", padx=45, pady=22, command=buttonAdd)
ButtonEqual = Button(root, text="=", padx=45, pady=22, command=buttonEqual)
ButtonClear = Button(root,
                     text="Clear",
                     padx=37,
                     pady=22,
                     command=lambda: buttonClear())

ButtonSubtract = Button(root,
                        text="-",
                        padx=45,
                        pady=22,
                        command=buttonSubtract)
ButtonMultiply = Button(root,
                        text="*",
                        padx=45,
                        pady=22,
                        command=buttonMultiply)
ButtonDivide = Button(root, text="/", padx=45, pady=22, command=buttonDivide)

Button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
Button2.grid(row=3, column=1)
Button3.grid(row=3, column=2)

Button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
Button6.grid(row=2, column=2)

Button7.grid(row=1, column=0)
Button8.grid(row=1, column=1)
Button9.grid(row=1, column=2)

Button0.grid(row=4, column=1)

ButtonAdd.grid(row=1, column=4)
ButtonEqual.grid(row=4, column=2)
ButtonClear.grid(row=4, column=0)

ButtonSubtract.grid(row=2, column=4)
ButtonMultiply.grid(row=4, column=4)
ButtonDivide.grid(row=3, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried it the first time it did not work for multiplication. After I fixed  the indentation for the if statements it worked. Try that.

Comment: I swear, I'm blind! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the part of if loop on buttonEqual function so that every statement get a test separately, Here is my solution:

```
def buttonEqual():
  secondNumber = box.get()
  box.delete(0, END)

  if math == "addition":
    box.insert(0, numOne + int(secondNumber))

  if math == "subtraction":
    box.insert(0, numOne - int(secondNumber))

  if math == "multiplication":
    box.insert(0, numOne*int(secondNumber))

  if math == "division":
    box.insert(0, numOne/int(secondNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout was annoying me, so thought I'd share this. I get the screenWidth then position the buttons screenWidth / 4.
Also added the layout in order at the bottom.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

box = Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=10)
box.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=0, pady=0)
root.update()
width = box.winfo_width()
height = box.winfo_height()

def buttonClick(number):
  current = box.get()
  box.delete(0, END)
  box.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))


def buttonClear():
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonAdd():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "addition"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonEqual():
  secondNumber = box.get()
  box.delete(0, END)

  if math == "addition":
    box.insert(0, numOne + int(secondNumber))

  if math == "subtraction":
    box.insert(0, numOne - int(secondNumber))

  if math == "multiplication":
    print(numOne * int(secondNumber))
    box.insert(0, numOne * int(secondNumber))

  if math == "division":
    box.insert(0, numOne / int(secondNumber))


def buttonSubtract():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "subtraction"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)

def buttonMultiply():
    
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "multiplication"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


def buttonDivide():
  firstNumber = box.get()
  global numOne
  global math
  math = "division"
  numOne = int(firstNumber)
  box.delete(0, END)


Button1 = Button(root,
                 text="1",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(1))
Button2 = Button(root,
                 text="2",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(2))
Button3 = Button(root,
                 text="3",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(3))
Button4 = Button(root,
                 text="4",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(4))
Button5 = Button(root,
                 text="5",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(5))
Button6 = Button(root,
                 text="6",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(6))
Button7 = Button(root,
                 text="7",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(7))
Button8 = Button(root,
                 text="8",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(8))
Button9 = Button(root,
                 text="9",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(9))
Button0 = Button(root,
                 text="0",
                 padx=width / 4,
                 pady=22,
                 command=lambda: buttonClick(0))

ButtonAdd = Button(root, text="+", padx=width / 4, pady=22, command=buttonAdd)
ButtonSubtract = Button(root,
                        text="-",
                        padx=width / 4,
                        pady=22,
                        command=buttonSubtract)
ButtonMultiply = Button(root,
                        text="*",
                        padx=width / 4,
                        pady=22,
                        command=buttonMultiply)
ButtonDivide = Button(root, text="/", padx=width / 4, pady=22, command=buttonDivide)
ButtonEqual = Button(root, text="=", padx=width / 4, pady=22, command=buttonEqual)
ButtonClear = Button(root,
                    text="C",
                    padx=width / 4,
                    pady=22,
                    command=lambda: buttonClear())


Button7.grid(row=1, column=0)
Button8.grid(row=1, column=1)
Button9.grid(row=1, column=2)
ButtonAdd.grid(row=1, column=3)

Button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
Button6.grid(row=2, column=2)
ButtonSubtract.grid(row=2, column=3)

Button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
Button2.grid(row=3, column=1)
Button3.grid(row=3, column=2)
ButtonDivide.grid(row=3, column=3)

ButtonClear.grid(row=4, column=0)
Button0.grid(row=4, column=1)
ButtonEqual.grid(row=4, column=2)
ButtonMultiply.grid(row=4, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```